# Keras difference between GRU and GRUCell

Tags: neural-networks, keras

In Keras documentation at this page, https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/, I wonder what's the difference between **GRU** and **GRUCell**, which one I should use if I'd like to create a GRU recurrent network. Similarly, I have confusion between **LSTM** and **LSTMCell**, and **RNN** and **SimpleRNN**.

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py): the class inheritance is like

```
Layer => RNN
Layer => GRUCell
Layer => LSTMCell

RNN => SimpleRNN
RNN => GRU
RNN => LSTM
```

Also,

- [**GRU** calls **GRUCell**](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1557)
- [**LSTM** calls **LSTMCell**](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2080)

Comment: This question has been [answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50608080/2099607).

Answer (score 1):

In GRU/LSTM Cell, there is no option of return_sequences. That means it is just a cell of an unfolded GRU/LSTM unit.

The argument of GRU/LSTM i.e. return_sequences, if return_sequences=True, then returns all the output state of the GRU/LSTM.

GRU/LSTM Cell computes and returns only one timestamp.

But, GRU/LSTM can return sequences of all timestamps.

In Figure 1, the unit in loop is GRU/LSTM.
In Figure 2, the cells shown are GRU/LSTM Cell which is an unfolded GRU/LSTM unit.

[image]

[image]